# MsBuild Subversion error The element <Project> is unrecognised

Tags: .net, svn, msbuild

I am trying to write an Msbuild script that will retrieve a Solution held in subversion to a local path, and then build the solution.

When executing from a command line I am getting the error - MSB4060 The element  is unrecognised, or not supported in this context. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
<project name="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003>">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RepositoryPath>http://Path<RepositoryPath>
    <svnUsername>USERNAME</svnUsername>
    <svnPassword>PASSWORD</svnPassword>
    <LocalPath>LOCAL_PATH_TO_COMPILE_SOLUTION</LocalPath>
    <solutionFileName>SOLUTION_FILENAME</solutionFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--<ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>-->

  <Import Project="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <Target Name="GetSource">
    <Message Text="Checking out trunk into $(LocalPath)" />
    <SvnCheckout RepositoryPath="$(RepositoryPath)"
        LocalPath="$(LocalPath)"
        UserName="$(svnUsername)"
        Password="$(svnPassword)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
    </SvnCheckout>
    <Message Text="Have got revision: $(Revision)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="GetSource;Clean;" />

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(LocalPath)$(solutionFileName)" Targets="Clean;Rebuild" />
  </Target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use upper-case `Project` root element instead lower-cased `project` in your sample
- use correct namespace `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"` (i.e. remove `>` before closing quote)
- fix closing tag for `RepositoryPath`

i.e. - just produce valid MSBUILD XML project